# Laravel 6 - MariaDB 10.1: Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] migration error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I have custom migration:

**Code:**

```
// Groups migration
Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
    $table->timestamps();
});

// Clients migration
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('fullname');
    $table->integer('phone');
    $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('can_get_congratulations')->default(false);
    $table->unsignedInteger('group_id')->default(null);
    $table->foreign('group_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('groups')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->boolean('status')->default(true);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I run this migration file then get error message:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `taxisms`.`#sql-1cc0_65c` (errno: 150 "Foreign
>   key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `clients` add
>   constraint `clients_group_id_foreign` foreign key (`group_id`)
>   references `groups` (`id`) on delete cascade)

[image]

Where I have an error in my migration code?

Comment: It's `cascade`, not `casecade`

Comment: @aynber I change to `cascade` but also get error. See to updated question

Comment: Can you show your `groups` migration as well?

Comment: @aynber see to updated question

Comment: If I remember correctly, the column definitions need to match on both sides. Since `groups.id` is an unsigned big integer, `group_id` will need to be as well. Change `$table->unsignedInteger('group_id')` to `$table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id')`

Comment: Perfect @aynber. You're right, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column needs to match on both sides. Since `groups.id` is an unsigned big integer, group_id will need to be as well. Change

```
$table->unsignedInteger('group_id')
```

to

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id')
```